# Read multiple lines from console in Java, issue with last line

Tags: java, console, lines

I want to load multiple lines from console. I paste text into console, this text has more lines. Last line doesn't want to load, its because there is missing \n. I am not able to add \n in console, because when I paste it, it runs immediately. Another issue is that while doesn't want to end. It loads everything expect last line and doesn't end.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String lineNew;

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            lineNew = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(lineNew);
            lines.add(lineNew);         
        }
```

Comment: It loads the last line ... when you press 'return' to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a check if your input is too short and if yes, break.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lines {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String lineNew;

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            lineNew = input.nextLine();
            if (lineNew.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(lineNew);
            lines.add(lineNew);
        }

        System.out.println("Content of List<String> lines:");
        for (String string : lines) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, `isEmpty()` is better. I modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "if your input is too short and if yes, break."? I guess you meant to use an empty line as the termination condition, but this isn't quite clear from this sentence :).

Answer (score 0):

You should press ctrl+z(ctrl+d) to terminate it.